# Chopping Doubles in C#

Tags: c#

I apologize is this is a duplicate and I just could not phrase the question properly to find it.

This seems like a trivial task but I was looking for a simple way to chop everything after the decimal place off my doubles.

I tried using the `%` operator, but it fails on negatives, and all the `Math.Round` functions round away from `0` (or evenly) instead of to `0`.

I realize I could construct such a function from the math I have available to me, but I was hoping there was an implementation in place so I did not have to write a long line of `Math.Floor` and/or `Math.Abs`

Comment: @Ray - what is Math.Floor(-1.2)

Comment: Math.Floor goes the wrong way for negative numbers, eg Math.Floor(-4.4) == -5.

Comment: Yeah I just figured that out, good point

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Math.Truncate
```

?

Comment: Yes, thank you.  Apparently searches for: chop, round to zero, and convert, did not produce this result for me.

Answer (score 4):

Obviously the answers you've gotten for Truncate are correct - but just a couple of things I've learned over the years.

- If you're doing it for display, you
  can usually avoid it with a string
  format like {0:N0}
- Doubles are by
  design imprecise which means you
  should be suspicious any time you
  have to use a double with the ==
  operator, even if you've just
  truncated it. Instead of truncating
  you may wish to make sure the
  absolute value of the difference
  between two doubles is < 1.

Answer (score 3):

[Math.Truncate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.truncate.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
double oldDouble = 5.555555;
double d = (int)oldDouble;
Console.Out.WriteLine(d); // prints 5
```

Is that what you meant?